# Context menu not being assigned to the specific element

Tags: javascript

In the below code.. I create new divs everytime a button is clicked and create a context menu along with that div, but for some reason even tho i append the context menu to the div created.. for the first div it shows up fine, but for all other divs the menu shows up behind them(Added reference images of first div created and how it shows up on all other).. not sure why this is happening. Can anyone help?

```
var sources = document.getElementById("sourceList").getElementsByTagName("a"); //Sources list retrieval

function windowProperties(containment, x, y, width, height) {
  //New Window Style and jQuery Functions

  $(containment).append(
    '<div class="windows" id="window' +
      divCount +
      '"><p id="windowName' +
      divCount +
      '"></p><p id="para' +
      divCount +
      '">Source</p></div>'
  );
  var nWindow = document.getElementById("window" + divCount);
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("para" + divCount);
  var windowName = document.getElementById("windowName" + divCount);

  //COntext menu creation..
  $(nWindow).append(
    '<div id="menu"><a href="#">Bring Forward</a><a href="#">Send Backward</a><hr /><a href="#">Delete Window  </a></div>'
  );

  var i = document.getElementById("menu").style;
  if (nWindow.addEventListener) {
    nWindow.addEventListener(
      "contextmenu",
      function(e) {
        var posX = e.clientX;
        var posY = e.clientY;
        menu(posX, posY);
        e.preventDefault();
      },
      false
    );
    document.addEventListener(
      "click",
      function(e) {
        i.opacity = "0";
        setTimeout(function() {
          i.visibility = "hidden";
        }, 501);
      },
      false
    );
  }

  function menu(x, y) {
    i.top = y + "px";
    i.left = x + "px";
    i.visibility = "visible";
    i.opacity = "1";
  }

  paragraph.style.color = "black";
  paragraph.style.fontSize = "20px";
  paragraph.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  paragraph.style.padding = "20px";
  paragraph.style.textAlign = "center";

  windowName.style.color = "black";
  windowName.style.fontSize = "20px";
  windowName.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  windowName.style.padding = "10px";
  windowName.style.textAlign = "center";
  windowName.innerHTML = "Window " + divCount;

  nWindow.style.width = currentWidth + "px"; //680
  nWindow.style.position = "absolute";
  nWindow.style.height = currentHeight + "px"; //294.75
  nWindow.style.opacity = "0.5";
  nWindow.style.background = "#f8f8f8";
  nWindow.style.border = "2px solid Black";
  nWindow.style.zIndex = "200";
  nWindow.style.top = currentY + "px";
  nWindow.style.left = currentX + "px";

  $(function() {
    var x, y;
    $.fn.getPosition = function() {
      var results = $(this).position();
      results.right = results.left + $(this).width();
      results.bottom = results.top + $(this).height();
      return results;
    };

    $(nWindow).resizable({
      maxWidth: 1356,
      maxHeight: 585.5,
      grid: [3, 4],
      aspectRatio: true
    });

    $(nWindow).draggable({
      cursor: "move",
      snapTolerance: "20",
      snap: nWindow,
      containment: container,
      stop: function(e, ui) {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition());
      }
    });

    $(sources).draggable({
      cursor: "pointer",
      helper: "clone",
      appendTo: nWindow
    });

    $(nWindow).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      accept: sources,
      drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(paragraph)
          .text(ui.draggable.text())
          .appendTo(nWindow);
        console.log(nWindow);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

[Div 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbNlS.png)

[All other divs created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duqbo.png)

Comment: Not a solution, but when you're working with dynamic HTML, you should not use `id`s, use classes to group elements, and the DOM tree and the DOM relation properties of the elements to get a reference to the needed elements.

Comment: Maybe you should try adding a higher z-index value to the divs either through CSS or JS

Comment: ive tried that, but doesnt seem to work